# How to register angular module in mean io package?

Tags: angularjs, mean

What should I do to register module in mean.io package? 
I want to register: [['angular-redactor']](https://github.com/TylerGarlick/angular-redactor) . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
bower install angular-redactor
```

in your app.js file.

```
angular.module('app', ['angular-redactor']);
```

here app is you application name

Comment: In mean.io it actually doesn't work like that. I know I should put it somewhere in app.js but do not know how and where.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `angular-redactor.js` in the `Assets.json` file. You should also add it to your `init.js` and then you can use it in your app.js by injecting it.